# How to run all files in a directory in Python

Tags: python, file, directory, file-processing

I want to draw a graph based on a text file read from a directory. I have figured out a way draw the graphs by reading one file at a time but I now want to open all files in the directory so that all the graphs can be drawn at once. When I run this code a value error saying that it can't convert string to float: 'G' message is displayed. I believe it is referring to the float methods used in the for loops but this wasn't a problem when I was handelling one text file at a time.

```
import os

path = r"path_name_of_folder"
fileList = os.listdir(path)
xCoor = []
yCoor = []

for file in fileList:
    open(file)
    #adds data
    for nums, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if nums % 3 == 1:
            xCoor.append(float(line))
        if nums % 3 == 2:
            yCoor.append(float(line))

#plots the given data
plt.plot(xCoor,yCoor, color = 'red', marker = 'o')
# adds title
plt.title('Prjectile PATH', fontsize = 20)
#adds labels on axes 
plt.xlabel('Distance', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Height', fontsize = 14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show();
```

Comment: Just use threading and use your working code for opening one file at a time. Just an idea don’t know if it will work

Comment: Why you dont close the files?

Comment: Please post sample data of your input .TXT file. @Jeff